# Facebook SDK: Is signed_request an alternative to access_code?

Tags: facebook

I hope my question doesnt sound stupid, But i really want to know this..

Is signed_request an alternative to access_code?
If so, How do i receive the signed_request for desktop clients?

I mean flow that i follow in my desktop client is:

1. Call `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=publish_stream`
2. Take the access_token returned from (1) and fetch user information.

So will 1. and 2. be merged in a single request call to signed_request which says it will give the JSON object of user information in it.

How to make this call to get signed_request for desktop clients?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with your theory here:

1. In order to get a valid access_token within the signed_request, you'll still need to authenticate and request permission from a user, so in that case it's probably simpler to use the authentication flow fully rather than trying to parse the signed_request.
2. As stated in the [Signed Request docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) you will not receive any signed_request if you are building a desktop/device app.